# Why does my in for each loop just add the last element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I’m recently working with jQuery and I have a question I have two products to which I want to add a value, to each his own. But at the moment it only adds the last element to both. How is this fixed?

My jquery:

```
$('.count').on('blur', function getTotalPrice(){
    var name = $(this).parent().parent().find('.name').html();
    var count = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "cart",
        data: "name=" + name + "&count=" + count,
        success: function(data){

            $("#totalPrice").text("Total price: " + data['totalPrice'].toFixed(2)).wrap("<h4></h4>");
            $("#productCount").text("(" + data['productCount'] + ")");
            console.log(data);

            $.each(data['totalPriceForOne'], function(key, value) {
                $(".totalPriceForOne").text((key * value).toFixed(2)); //field where i add      
            });
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

This what i got from jsnon:

```
> productCount: 2 
> totalPrice: 910  
> totalPriceForOne: {100.00: 1, 810.00: 1}
```

I need to add totalPriceForOne to each element. How can this be realized?

Comment: Please show what the desired output should be

Comment: You're updating the text of *every* `$(".totalPriceForOne")` element in each iteration of the loop. I don't know what your desired output is, but that's clearly not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's more than one `.totalPriceForOne` element, and each one needs to get the a different total from the object, you need to index it.

```
var index = 0;
$.each(data['totalPriceForOne'], function(key, value) {
    $(".totalPriceForOne").eq(index++).text((key * value).toFixed(2)); //field where i add      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.text(argument)` method replaces the text content of the element with the argument.

If you replace it with X and then immediately afterwards replace it with Y, then the X isn't going to stick around: It has been replaced.

---

Create your string outside the loop. `+=` each new value to it in the loop. Set the final result with `text()` at the end.

Or read the existing value in the loop and append to it:

```
foo.text( foo.text() + new_text )
```

Or use the `append()` method (warning: Watch out for text with HTML in it) instead of `text()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think your problem is here:

```
$(".totalPriceForOne").text((key * value).toFixed(2)); //field where i add
```

In fact in your loop, you will replace your previous value which it is't what you are looking for. I suggest you to use some think unique(like `id`) instead of using class selector.